# How to display an Alert box without any buttons in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder4.5

In ActionScript 3, by default, the Alert box has an OK button.  How can I display an Alert box without any buttons (not even the OK button)?

In my application, the Alert box would close on its own when a row is on blur.  My client does not want the OK button to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just have to make your own alert class.  It shouldn't be hard though, since those things' graphics are so primitive and bare.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I ended up doing it in TitleWindow and then use PopUpManager to display this TitleWindow.